# Proper way to create instances of models with has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have the following two classes and I'm struggling to find information about how to properly create an event and register users. Any help would be greatly appreciated - my code is below

```
class UserEvents < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :event
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :events, :through => :user_events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :attendees, :class_name => "User", :through :user_events
end
```

**Controller action for creating an event**

```
def create
    new_event = event.new(event_params)
    current_user.events << new_event
    new_event.attendees << current_user
    if new_event.save and current_user.save
        render json: new_event, status: :ok
    else
        render json: { errors: "Creation failed" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Am I going about this correctly? Should I be using an array of ID's to keep track of the attendees instead? I've also seen it done in ways similar to:

```
current_user.events.create ( ... )
```

I'm just not sure which approach would be best to take

Comment: What is user_outings?

Comment: @JimmyBaker Sorry, typo

Answer (score 1):

You can setup your event to accept nested attributes, then created all the necessary objects with a single save. Here's an example:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_events
  has_many :attendees, :class_name => "User", through: :user_outings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_events, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Then modify event_params in your controller to accept attributes for user_events. Example:

```
def event_params
  params.permit([
    :..event attributes...,
    user_events_attributes: [...user event attributes here...]
  ])
end
```

If it's only ever going to be the current user going to a new event, then this is overkill. But if you're adding other users to the event at event creation time, then this is how you'd do it.

If it's just the current user, then you can modify your create action to look like:

```
def create
    new_event = event.new(event_params)
    new_event.attendees << current_user

    if new_event.save and current_user.save
        render json: new_event, status: :ok
    else
        render json: { errors: "Creation failed" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

Edit: You can also do accepts_nested_attributes and use attendees but you may need to use the inverse_of option in your model. See https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through for more details.

Comment: Thanks, helpful. I've also seen it done in ways such as current_user.events.create ( ... ) , are you familiar with this method?

Comment: You can do this as well. It really depends on what the situation needs are. If you're only going to have the current user attend the event at the time of creation, then that's fine. But what if you wanted more than just the current user to attend the event? What if you had to pick from a list of users who should attend? Then you're better off posting the user ids with the params to create the event.

Comment: OK, great.  Last thing, I'm unsure of an example where adding attributes to the UserEvents (the bridge) class would be helpful... Wouldn't I pass the id's of people going into the params of the Events class instantiation?

Comment: more importantly, why did you remove the "current_user.events << new_event" line? How will I iterate through each users events in this case